# Running ejabberd inside docker container is causing PREVIOUS.LOG enoent crash

Tags: docker, ejabberd, crash-reports, mnesia, enoent

I'm running ejabberd inside a docker container. Everything was working fine for a long time but today I discovered that after an hour or so ejabberd is crashing. Here is the important part for the crash.log file.

```
/var/log/ejabberd/crash.log
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-12-27 16:00:25 =CRASH REPORT====
  crasher:
    initial call: disk_log:init/2
    pid: <0.169.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {{{failed,{error,{file_error,"/opt/ejabberd/database/ejabberd@localhost/PREVIOUS.LOG",enoent}}},[{disk_log,reopen,2}]},[{disk_log,do_exit,4,[{file,"disk_log.erl"},{line,1188}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}
    ancestors: [disk_log_sup,kernel_safe_sup,kernel_sup,<0.10.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.135.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 2586
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 40032
  neighbours:
2016-12-27 16:00:25 =SUPERVISOR REPORT====
     Supervisor: {local,disk_log_sup}
     Context:    child_terminated
     Reason:     {{failed,{error,{file_error,"/opt/ejabberd/database/ejabberd@localhost/PREVIOUS.LOG",enoent}}},[{disk_log,reopen,2}]}
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.169.0>},{name,disk_log},{mfargs,{disk_log,istart_link,undefined}},{restart_type,temporary},{shutdown,1000},{child_type,worker}]

2016-12-27 16:00:25 =ERROR REPORT====
** gen_event handler mnesia_event crashed.
** Was installed in mnesia_event
** Last event was: {mnesia_system_event,{mnesia_fatal,"~p~n",[{error,{"Cannot rename disk_log file",latest_log,"/opt/ejabberd/database/ejabberd@localhost/PREVIOUS.LOG",{log_header,trans_log,"4.3","4.12.3",ejabberd@localhost,{1482,854424,897044}},{file_error,"/opt/ejabberd/database/ejabberd@localhost/PREVIOUS.LOG",enoent}}}],<<131,108,0,0,0,24,104,2,100,0,9,99,114,97,115,104,105,110,102,111,104,2,107,0,4,126,112,126,110,108,0,0,0,1,104,2,
......
```

Based on the crash error log seems that is something with the logs rotation.

```
Cannot rename disk_log file",latest_log,"/opt/ejabberd/database/ejabberd@localhost/PREVIOUS.LOG
```

The strange thing is whenever I restart the container everything is working fine I obviously can see the `/opt/ejabberd/database/ejabberd@localhost/` directory with all the files there and also the `LATEST.LOG` file.
After an hour or so, it crashes and then everything inside `/opt/ejabberd/database/ejabberd@localhost/` is gone even the `ejabberd@localhost` dir is also deleted.

If I go inside the container I cannot create the directory again or any other files in `/opt/ejabberd/database/` directory.

```
$mkdir -p /opt/ejabberd/database/ejabberd@localhost

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/ejabberd/database/ejabberd@localhost’: No such file or directory
```

Does not seem to be a permissions issue

```
$ls -lh /opt/ejabberd/

drwxr-xr-x  0 ejabberd ejabberd    0 Dec 27 15:09 backup
drwxr-xr-x  2 ejabberd ejabberd 4.0K Dec 27 15:09 conf
drwxr-xr-x  0 ejabberd ejabberd    0 Dec 27 16:00 database
drwxr-xr-x  5 ejabberd ejabberd 4.0K Dec 27 15:09 extauth
-rw-r--r--  1 ejabberd ejabberd    0 Dec 27 15:09 first-start-done
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ejabberd ejabberd  747 Mar  2  2016 init.sh
drwxr-xr-x 15 ejabberd ejabberd 4.0K Jul 15 08:59 scripts
drwxr-xr-x  0 ejabberd ejabberd    0 Dec 27 16:00 ssl
drwxr-xr-x  0 ejabberd ejabberd    0 Dec 27 15:09 upload
```

Have to say that I did not have this before, does anybody experienced something similar inside a docker container with ejabberd ? 
Any thoughts about what would be causing this strange error ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems you have issues on the right for ejabberd user in the database directory.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond as you can see in the code ejabberd user has all the rights to the database folder is the owner.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond as you can see in the code ejabberd user has all the rights to the database folder, it's the owner.
Even inside the database `/opt/ejabberd/database/ejabberd@localhost` it's the owner for all the files. 
When I create the container everything is fine, I can even create, rename files (I tested) however at some point it fails and the container dies.

According to logs is when trying to rename LATEST.LOG to PREVIOUS.LOG but could not find the reason for that.

Good to mention that I have this same configuration running in another setups with no issues like this.

Comment: Not sure which container you are using, but I do not see what else it should be than a container rights.